# Autopostback textbox not retaining the values across postbacks with nested form tags

Tags: asp.net

Here the textbox with id as "a" retains the value after postbacks while textbox with id as "b"  not retains the value.Why this happens?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
         <asp:TextBox ID="a" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>
            <form action="javascript:myFunc();">
            <p>
                <input type="text" id="city-field" name="city" " />
                <input type="submit" value="Find" /></p>
            </form>
        </div>
           <asp:TextBox ID="b" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML does not support nested `<form>` tags.

The browser drops the inner `<form>`, then uses the inner `</form>` to close the outer `<form>`.
Therefore, the second textbox never gets posted back.

You can see this in Firebug.

Comment: Look at the `<form>` tag in the HTML tab.